# What is the best time to mention that I've edited my question/answer?

Tags: discussion, edits

We come across a lot of question/answers that have been edited by the OP. Sometimes, I However, I am unable to find a pattern in the way an OP mentions that the post has been edited by putting

```
**EDIT/UPDATE** : 
...the changes
..............
```

Some do right after a long time, some on the same day. Some do it after say a breaking API change or some when they find a new/better way to answer/ask question.

Any insight?

Comment: Any of those patterns should not be in the post.

Comment: Okay, and why tho?

Comment: Also closely related: [When is “EDIT”/“UPDATE” appropriate in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post) and [What's wrong with putting “EDIT: …” in the body of a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202472/whats-wrong-with-putting-edit-in-the-body-of-a-post)

Comment: We have the Edit timeline if we want to keep track of the revision. The question should be more readable with the edit directly in it. And not sitting at the end. And incomplete question with a chain of edit can be unreadable. And It can be a pain to logically sort everything.